# One-way synchronize with cp and busybox

Tags: cp, busybox, synchronization

I need to one-way synchronize local folders using only `cp` and/or other tools available in the BusyBox 1.35 which has no `rsync`. I was hoping for something like: `cp -auv /source/ /target`, but it won't delete eliminated items on the target. The target must end up being an exact copy of the source, but it's going to have most of it already, so just a few updating overwrites, new additions, and **removals** may be needed, without any interactive prompts.

UPDATE. <del>If `cp -auv /source/ /target` already does all that is needed for a one-way sync **except** deleting old stuff on the target, is there any command/script to "diff" the two folders and erase the items that are still present on the target? Maybe something like  `diff -qr /source /target | xargs rm -rf`, would that work?</del> BusyBox doesn't have `diff`

Comment: deleting the target and then copying over is not an option, right?

Comment: I ask because a system on which you don't have space for a rsync certainly won't have GB of data to synchronize.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks. Space is not a problem. It is a busybox inside a tiny initrd which needs to sync tens of MBs between drives before proceeding with the boot. Maybe one can add rsync inside busybox/initrd as an overkill alternative?!

Comment: don't think "I want that tool's functionality, so I include the tool" is generally overkill. A static rsync binary without SSL, IPv6, xxhash, lz4 and zstd support is 2.3 MB in size on x86_64, just tried.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you know where I can find that minimal static rsync binary. My whole initrd is 900Kb in comparison but I might have to add rsync to it after all. Do I need to know whether BusyBox 64bit or 32bit?!

Comment: I built it from source myself. Standard autoconf ./configure with a CFLAGS=-static and disabling all features individually

Answer (score 3):

Long ago I have been successfully using the following script under busybox 1.22.
It quick&dirty simulates **very basic** `rsync` functionalities (syncs based on time and size only + logging), **you should certainly review it first** and possibly enhance it for handling file deletions (`rsync --del` like feature)
Also note the final interactive part you could easily get rid of. :

```
#!/bin/sh  

echo "#############################################"
echo "SHELL : $SHELL"
echo "BASH : $BASH"
echo "TERM : $TERM"
DATENOW=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S` 
# last argument
LASTARG=`echo "$@" | awk ' { print $NF  }  '`
# penultimate argument
num_args=$# 
num_args_max=$num_args
let num_args=$num_args-1 
PENUARG=` echo "$@" | awk -v vk=$num_args ' { print $vk  }  ' `
TRG="$LASTARG"
echo "#############################################"

ProcedureStartCopyOneFile() {
  echo "*** COPY ***"
  echo "File not exists : $FILETRG" >> ~/.config/bashmv/bashmv.log
  echo -en "\r Copying ($i) (...)"
  echo "$i" | cpio -pvdmu "$TRG"
  echo -en "\r Copied ($i)."
  TRSS=` du -hs "$FILETRG" --apparent-size | cut -f 1 `
  SRSS=` du -hs "$i" --apparent-size | cut -f 1 ` 
  if  [ ! -d  "$i" ] &&  [ "$SRSS" != "$TRSS" ] ; then 
    echo "Different size: $FILETRG"
    echo "** WARNING **"
    echo "Different size: $FILETRG" >> ~/.config/bashmv/bashmv.log
    echo "** WARNING **" >> ~/.config/bashmv/bashmv.log
    exit
  else
    echo -en "\r Copied ($i) [OK]"
  fi
  echo "*** COPY OK ***"
  echo ".*.*"
}

ProcedureCopying() {

 echo "> Parameters: Source: $SRC  => Target: $TRG"


if [ -f "$SRC" ] || [  -d "$SRC" ] ; then 
  echo "Source: $SRC"
else
  echo "Directory or file source $SRC not found."
  exit
fi

if [ "$TRG" = "" ] ; then 
  exit
fi

if [ "$BASH" != "/bin/bash" ] ; then
  echo "Warning: You should use BASH : /bin/bash !"
  exit
else 
  echo "Intpreter BASH: $BASH [OK] "
fi

echo "** START ** "
[ ! -d ~/.config/bashmv ] && mkdir -p ~/.config/bashmv

[ ! -d  "$TRG" ] && mkdir -p "$TRG"
if [ "$LASTARG" = "--debug" ] ; then
  find "$SRC" -print
  exit
fi

find "$SRC" -print | grep -v "^$\|^#" | while read -r i ; do 
# echo "Processing $i"

FILETRG="${TRG}/${i}"
DATENOW=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S` 
echo "> Start: .*.* ($i)"
if [ !  -f "$FILETRG" ] && [ ! -d  "$i"  ] ; then 
  echo ".*.*"
  echo "*** COPY ***"
  echo "File not exists : $FILETRG" >> ~/.config/bashmv/bashmv.log
  echo "$i" | cpio -pvdmu "$TRG"
  TRSS=` du -hs "$FILETRG" --apparent-size | cut -f 1 `
  SRSS=` du -hs "$i" --apparent-size | cut -f 1 ` 
  if  [ ! -d  "$i" ] &&  [ "$SRSS" != "$TRSS" ] ; then 
    echo "Different size: $FILETRG"
    echo "** WARNING **"
    echo "Different size: $FILETRG" >> ~/.config/bashmv/bashmv.log
    echo "** WARNING **" >> ~/.config/bashmv/bashmv.log
    exit
  else
    echo "Copied ($i) [OK]"
  fi
  echo "*** COPY OK ***"
  echo ".*.*"

elif [  -d "$i" ] ; then
  mkdir -p "$FILETRG"
  echo "Creating $FILETRG"

elif [ ! -d "$i" ] ; then
  TRSS=` du -hs "$FILETRG" --apparent-size | cut -f 1 `
  SRSS=` du -hs "$i" --apparent-size | cut -f 1 ` 
  # echo "Source: $SRSS vs $TRSS"

  if  [ -d  "$i" ] ; then
    echo "Directory."
  fi

  if  [ ! -d  "$i" ] ; then
    if [ -f "$FILETRG" ] && [ "$SRSS" = "$TRSS" ] ; then 
      echo "file $FILETRG exists. [Same size]"
    fi

    if   [ "$SRSS111kkk" = "$TRSS" ] ; then 
      echo "Different size: $FILETRG"
      echo "** WARNING **"
      echo "Different size: $FILETRG" >> ~/.config/bashmv/bashmv.log
      echo "** WARNING **" >> ~/.config/bashmv/bashmv.log
      FILETRGERROR="${TRG}/Error/${i}"
      [ ! -d  "$TRG/Error" ] && mkdir -p "$TRG/Error"
      echo "$TRSS" | cpio -pvdmu   "$TRG/Error/${DATENOW}-${i}"
    fi
  fi
fi

done

echo "Finished!"

if [ "$LASTARG" = "--rm" ] ; then 
  echo "Delete the directory: $SRC [y/n] ? "
  read inpud
  [ "$inpud" = "n" ] && exit
  rm -rf "$SRC"
fi

exit
```

Full credits to some anonymous and serviceable author.

Comment: that does not depend on the bash extension being active in busybox's `make menuconfig`, right?

Comment: love this, by the way.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  Not sure about that ! I think I was running *ash* in these times (about 10 years ago but I cannot tell for sure) but I can remember that… I had loved this too… ;-)

Comment: that timeline puts it firmly in the "likely to work with a relatively minimal busybox" territory, I'd say!

Comment: Thanks for this. I won't use it until I decipher it though :) By the way, our version is BusyBox 1.35

Comment: Have found https://github.com/Fitus/Zaloha2.sh too, an even larger script. So might just adapt yours a lot smaller in comparison

Comment: Wow! And what a documentation !!

Answer (score 1):

Towards an answer, needs a final removal step, review, critique. Firstly we update the target. We assume the items on the target can't be newer than the source, that is the source is the only updating agent for the target. We still need to remove the old items that were eliminated from the source and `cp` doesn't do this. We'll use @ceving's grep command as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51761017/612313

```
cp -auv /source/. /target
grep -v -F -x -f <(find /source -type f -printf '%P\n') <(find /target -type f -printf '%P\n')
```

This will print the paths, relative to /target/, for all the obsolete files in all the subfolders of /target but not the subfolders themselves. Now I just need to learn how to feed this output to `rm /target/$1` and how to find and remove empty subfolders as a final step.

Maybe this (getting too long a one-liner):

```
for i in $(grep -v -F -x -f <(find /source -type f -printf '%P\n') <(find /target -type f -printf '%P\n')); do echo /target/$i; done
```

Alternatively,

```
grep -v -F -x -f <(find /source -type f -printf '%P\n') <(find /target -type f -printf '%P\n') | while read i; do echo /target/$i; done
```

Even shorter(?), as we can send the whole output to `echo` (`rm`) but have to change working folder first as we won't be able to append /target/ to each line anymore

```
cd /target
echo $(grep -v -F -x -f <(find /source -type f -printf '%P\n') <(find . -type f -printf '%P\n'))
```

**My best cadidate solution so far:**

```
mkdir /target
pushd /target
cp -auv /source/. .
rm -v $(grep -v -F -x -f <(find /source -type f -printf '%P\n') <(find . -type f -printf '%P\n'))
find . -empty -type d -delete
popd
```

(*except any file which for some reason is newer on the target won't be touched; works if this script is the only updater of the target*)

Doubts to be tested inside `initrd`: which shell are we in? If it's Ash or something then `pushd/pod` might not be available, and neither the `$()` expansion. Will report my findings...

Comment: If this precisely fits your need then this is the best solution ! +1 & Congrats ! (I'd probably check the exit status of pushd and cp though)

Comment: @MC68020 Yes, ```/target``` had better exist, otherwise we'd messing with whatever is the current folder, LOL :)